# How to reuse data in XML

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to create a group of elements which contain certain values. 
Then I want to name this group. Finally, I want to refer this group.
Something like this:

```
<catalog type="expensive">
  <powder>25</powder>
  <cream>110</cream>
</catalog>

<catalog type="normal">
  <powder>5</powder>
  <cream>45</cream>
</catalog>

<person>
  <name>Jim</name>
  <catalog type="expensive">
    <powder>25</powder>
    <cream>110</cream>
  </catalog>
</person>
```

Instead of repeating expensive catalog with every person element, is there a way for person element to refer to already created expensive catalog group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you already did it in your example - if `type` uniquely identifies the catalog you can write something like:

```
<person> 
  <name>Jim</name> 
  <catalogRef type="expensive" /> 
</person>
```

and you are done - the information you need is all there. If `type` is not unique you could add another unique attribute to identify each catalog (typically `id`).

The longer answer would require some details on how you want to process and use this XML - if you want to transform it in some way using XSLTs then the above approach is fine - you can access the catalog of each person using something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="catalogType" select="catalogRef/@type" />
<xsl:variable name="catalog" select="/*/catalog[@type=$catalogType]" />
```

assuming the current node is the person element and that all the catalog definitions are in the same XML just under the root.